# How to query all records that has an array attribute that contains specific set of elements in Mongoid?

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

Here is the setup.

```
user has_many skills
skills belongs_to user
```

I would have to find out all users that have skills with ids 1,2 and 3

I can use intersection of three user collections.

```
Skill.find(1).users & Skill.find(2).users & Skill.find(3).users
```

But this does not seem efficient. Is there a query in Mongoid/MongoDB that resembles the following?

```
User.where(:skill_ids.contains=>[1,2,3])
```

PS: I know Mongoid gives the in keyword:

```
User.where(:skill_id.in=>[1,2,3])
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you're looking for MongoDB's [`$all`](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24all) query operator:

> **$all**
>
> The `$all` operator is similar to `$in`, but instead of matching any value in the specified array all values in the array must be matched.
>   [...]
>   An array can have more elements than those specified by the `$all` criteria. `$all` specifies a minimum set of elements that must be matched.

Mongoid provides access to `$all` through [`all_in`](http://mongoid.org/docs/querying/criteria.html#all_in) which I think is available as `.all` on symbols so I think this:

```
User.where(:skill_id.all => [1,2,3])
```

should work for you.